# Get Computer Manufacturer and Model # in Windows 8 Application using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows

I am trying to get information about the computers/tablets running my app.  This is for analytics purposes.  Specifically I'd like to know the Manufacturer and Model #.

Ideally I would get information like:

```
Manufacturer: Toshiba
Model: Satellite S850-BT3N22
```

But I would take whatever I could get.  I've spent some time trying my own solutions as well as finding it on SO, but I'm not able to find a solution.

I have spent some time trying to get this with:

```
var hardwareToken = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.getPackageSpecificToken(null);
var idReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.fromBuffer(hardwareToken.id);        
var idArray = new Array(hardwareToken.id.length);
idReader.readBytes(idArray);
```

So now idArray is an array of integers.  I've tried converting this byte array to a String, but it converts it to a bunch of what look like Chinese characters.  I don't think this is what this hardwareToken.id is meant for.  Here is sample output from the javascript console of the idReader array:

```
idArray.toString();
"3,0,26,139,5,0,90,224,6,0,1,0,4,0,246,50,1,0,248,181,2,0,80,124,9,0,250,137"
```

The next thing I tried is emulating the "Device Enumeration Sample" from msdn here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Device-Enumeration-Sample-a6e45169

From this I'm able to see several different devices that are on my network, and I'm able to get System.ItemNameDisplay and System.Devices.ModelName, but I don't see a way to distinguish which device is the computer.  It gives all of the Pnp devices.

If anybody can help me get this information I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for this:

Use Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation, like so:

```
var deviceInfo = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
var manufacturer = deviceInfo.systemManufacturer;
var productName = deviceInfo.systemProductName;
```

here is sample data:

```
manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
productName: 700Z3A/700Z4A/700Z5A/700Z5B
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like [BrowserSpy](http://browserspy.dk/) to get this information.  They're pretty much on the cutting edge of this field.

As far as I can tell, there's no pure Javascript way of doing this.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431).

As far as the call you specified, you can find out the following information:

```
CPU ID of the processor
Size of the memory
Serial number of the disk device
Network adapter (such as NIC MAC address)
Audio adapter
Docking station
Bluetooth address
Mobile broadband device ID
BIOS
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with this today.  The key is to look at the System.Devices.LocalMachine attribute on the DeviceContainer, which will be true if the device represents the local system (see the device container attributes at ).

What follows is a quick-and-dirty C# example based on the MS device enumeration sample; hopefully it should be pretty easy to take the JS version of that sample and adapt it in the same way:

```
string[] properties = { "System.Devices.LocalMachine", "System.ItemNameDisplay", "System.Devices.ModelName", "System.Devices.ModelNumber", "System.Devices.Manufacturer" };
var containers = await PnpObject.FindAllAsync(PnpObjectType.DeviceContainer, properties);

foreach (PnpObject container in containers)
{
    bool localMachine = (bool)container.Properties["System.Devices.LocalMachine"];
    if (localMachine)
    {
        string name = (string)container.Properties["System.ItemNameDisplay"];
        string modelName = (string)container.Properties["System.Devices.ModelName"];
        string modelNumber = (string)container.Properties["System.Devices.ModelNumber"];
        string manufacturer = (string)container.Properties["System.Devices.Manufacturer"];
        // do as you like now...
        break;
    }
}
```